# PHP: Determine number of characters that come before a dash in a string

Tags: php

If I have a bunch of strings like **XXX-WYC-5b**, where XXX is any value between 1 and 999, how do I determine the length of XXX?

So I might have:
1: 6-WYC-5b
2: 32-WYC-5b
3: 932-W-5b
4: 22-XYQ-5b
5: 914-WYC-5b

And I want it to tell me the length of XXX, so:
1: 1 character
2: 2 characters
3: 3 characters
4: 2 characters
5: 3 characters

I would also like to know the value itself, so:
1: 6
2: 32
3: 932
4: 22
5: 914

I keep thinking there's a way to do this using substr_count() and explode(), but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's built-in string position function.  Because it starts counting at 0, you don't even have to adjust the output:

```
$pos = strpos($string, "-");
```

For the second part, use PHP's substring function:

```
return substr($string, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: Works perfect. So simple. Thanks for helping me through my moment of being brain-dead. :)

Answer (score 0):

a different approach you may want to try:

```
    <?php 

    $str[] = '6-WYC-5b';
    $str[] = '32-WYC-5b';
    $str[] = '932-W-5b';
    $str[] = '22-XYQ-5b';
    $str[] = '914-WYC-5b';

    foreach($str as $v){
        $result[] = getval($v);
    }

    function getval($value){
        $seg = explode('-',$value);
        return array('int'=>$seg[0],'intlen'=>strlen($seg[0]),'char'=>$seg[1],'charlen'=>strlen($seg[1]),'last'=>$seg[2],'lastlen'=>strlen($seg[2]));
    }
print_r($result);
    ?>

outputs:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [int] => 6
                [intlen] => 1
                [char] => WYC
                [charlen] => 3
                [last] => 5b
                [lastlen] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [int] => 32
                [intlen] => 2
                [char] => WYC
                [charlen] => 3
                [last] => 5b
                [lastlen] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [int] => 932
                [intlen] => 3
                [char] => W
                [charlen] => 1
                [last] => 5b
                [lastlen] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [int] => 22
                [intlen] => 2
                [char] => XYQ
                [charlen] => 3
                [last] => 5b
                [lastlen] => 2
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [int] => 914
                [intlen] => 3
                [char] => WYC
                [charlen] => 3
                [last] => 5b
                [lastlen] => 2
            )

    )
```

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Might come in handy for me. Thank you!

Comment: np, case you want togo the array approach